# BadStatusLine exception when using Selenium with Phantomjs

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm trying to visit page and get its' source using selenium. So I've got simple function that looks like this:

```
def visit_url(url):
    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    if not url.startswith("http://") and not url.startswith("https://"):
        url = "http://" + url
    browser.get(url)
    html = browser.page_source
    browser.quit()
    return html
```

I tried it on different pages and it seemed to be working fine. Unfortunately, I came across page (`www.wp.pl`) that causes `BadStatusLine` exception. So I changed driver to `webdriver.Firefox()` and invoked this function again and this time it worked. What could be causing this difference in webdrivers behaviours? The version of selenium that I'm using is 2.53.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that some pages require specifying user-agent so I used a solution found [here](https://coderwall.com/p/9jgaeq/set-phantomjs-user-agent-string) and changed my function to:

```
def visit_url(url):
    dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
    dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (
        "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/53 "
        "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.87"
    )
    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap)
    if not url.startswith("http://") and not url.startswith("https://"):
        url = "http://" + url
    browser.get(url)
    html = browser.page_source
    browser.quit()
    return html
```